# Using generic ListView with pagination. Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

Now I have the following code in the `views.py`:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "qa_forum/index.html"
    context_object_name = 'question_list'
    paginate_by = 25
```

Its work good, but it retrieves **all** questions in the database (including closed  and "future" questions).

In the `models.py` I have the following manager:

```
class ActiveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(ActiveManager, self).get_query_set(). \
                .filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), is_active=True
                ).order_by('-pub_date')
```

That helps to get only *active* question from the db.

But I don't know how to use it properly with the *generic* `ListView`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of implementing `modelManager` you can set the [queryset on the `ListView` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#viewing-subsets-of-objects) as:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = "qa_forum/index.html"
    context_object_name = 'question_list'
    paginate_by = 25
    queryset = Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now(), 
                                       is_active=True).order_by('-pub_date')
```

---

If you want to go by `modelManager` method, you can set queryset as

```
    class IndexView(generic.ListView):
        #if you have set manger as active_objects in Question model
        queryset = Question.active_objects.filter()
```